# Give privileges to run stored procedure avoiding direct updates

Tags: sql-server

I have a particular schema (`abc`) in my SQL Server 2014 database. I want people to execute stored procedures under that schema avoiding them to do updates directly on the tables under that schema.

I created a server role (`RoleA`) and a server user (`UserA`) assigned to that role, then I assigned UserA to my database giving these permissions:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON SCHEMA ::abc TO UserA
DENY UPDATE on SCHEMA ::abc TO UserA
```

When I try to update a table on abc schema, works file, it doesn't allow me to do the update.

The problem comes with the execution of the stored procedure, inside has a specific logic that drop constraints, delete data and regenerate constraints again, but I believe because drop constraints is altering the table, it doesn't allow me because of the deny update I put.

Is there any way to whatever is inside the stored procedure can be executed even if I have explicitly the deny update?

Comment: Have you looked at [EXECUTE AS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/execute-as-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)?

Comment: Hi Sean, I'm using SQL 2014, not sure is supported, besides if I can do it, I need to update the stored procedures to explicitly include the "WITH EXECUTE AS 'MyUser'" and I don't want to do that

Comment: I don't think you need DENY UPDATE on SCHEMA ::abc TO UserA. The execute privileges only grants the user to run the SP in the schema

Comment: Yes because at the same time I don't want any user to do direct updates on any table under that schema

Comment: Yes it is supported in 2014.

Comment: Ok but I can't modify the stored procedure :(, there is no other way ?

Answer (score 0):

As long as the logged in user is not the schema (abc) owner, then they will have no access to the schema or anything inside it. If, however, the user is the schema owner, then they will have irrevocable access to do anything and everything to the schema (as they own it).

The stored procedure will, by default, run as the user who owns it (schema owner), and not the user that executes it - so as long as the procedure, and objects that it access/modifies are owned by the same user, then it will be able to execute successfully.

Therefore, if the user's only permission on the schema is execute access on that procedure, then they will be able to execute that procedure, and not be able to peform any other operation on that schema directly. As a result, the deny operation is not needed.

The following gives guidance on object ownership and user/schema separation

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/ownership-and-user-schema-separation-in-sql-server